# Druid spec to convert one datatype into another

Tags: druid

I want to a Druid  spec which will convert the datatype of a perticular column  from one datatype to another datatype .

Answer (score 0):

Use below it will work as an e.g.

```
"dimensionsSpec": {
      "dimensions": [
       "mtime",
        "name1",
        "name2",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "name": "sal"
        },
        {
          "type": "long",
          "name": "amount"
        },
        "response",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "name": "response_id"
        },
        "venue_name"
      ]
    }
```